# Unable to expand table if new values are copied and pasted from another table in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy values from one table(table1) and paste it on another table (table2) using vba macro.

Ex: Sheet1 "data" is filtered by header "type" with "blanks" and resulted values are copied except headers and pasted below table2 (next to last row) in sheet2

The issue here is macro is working fine but the table2 where the values are pasted doesn't expand when it is pasted.

I have tried enabling "include rows and column in table" in autocheck option still table is not expanding.

I've tried the following:

```
range("Check_for_Alias[[#Headers],[Type]]").Select 
Selection.AutoFilter 
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Check_for_Alias").range.AutoFilter Field:=18, _
Criteria1:="=" range("Check_for_Alias[Type]").Offset(1, 0).Select 
range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select 
range("Check_for_Alias[[Team]:[Type]]").Select 
range("Check_for_Alias[Type]").Offset(1, 0).Activate
Selection.Copy Sheets("Share_point").Select 
ActiveSheet.range("C7").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.paste
```

Comment: First I would suggest to avoid `Select` and `Activate` as much as possible. Most of the time in automation, it is not necessary. Especially where you select ranges after eachother without doing anything with the selections. Second, It might be me but I never see you copying anything. I only see paste in the last row.

Comment: Thank u for ur reply Alex, I am a beginner in vba using record macro to develop the macro, the code which i used is working great. What happens is the selection copied is moved to last row by xldown and moves one cell down by offset(1,0) and past the selection copied. The problem is the table doesn’t expand after the selection is pasted, is there a way i can add a code to expand table or this code should be altered?